# N1QL query in Java with WHERE and LIKE and underscore

Tags: java, sql, nosql, couchbase, sql++

I am trying to query all documents with id matching my key, ex: **example_key_123**

```
Statement statement = select("META().id").from(i("bucketname")).where(x("META().id").like(x("'example\\_key%'")));
N1qlQueryResult res = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(statement));
```

This is the code I am trying, but it keeps giving me all documents in this bucket, not only the ones that match.
When I do it without escaping the underscore, this way:

```
Statement statement = select("META().id").from(i("bucketname")).where(x("META().id").like(x("'example_key%'")));
```

It goes on forever and gives me a timeout. Trying with one \ gives me a compiler error in intelliJ saying "Illegal escape character in string literal"

I am using Couchbase server 4.5 and Java SDK 2.7.15

**EDIT**

Solution was to use quadruple backslashes like this:

```
example\\\\_key%
```

Comment: The query that @vsr has works for me, but I suspect Java is escaping the slash characters first. So you might need to escape the slashes. Something like `WHERE META().id LIKE "example\\\\_key%";` maybe?

Comment: Also, the single quotes inside of the string may not be needed, and they may or may not be a problem. Maybe try: `like(x("example\\\\_key%")))`

Comment: Well would you se, quadruple backslashes actually worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following is right query. You can try with SQL statement as string ( without DSL statement)

```
SELECT META().id 
FROM default 
WHERE META().id LIKE "example\\_key%";
```

May be try this.

```
like(s("example\\_key%"))
```

Comment: Did you tried SQL query in the cbq shell or Query Work bench or REST API.